# Максимальное значение android:versionCode

Tags: android

Есть ли максимальное значение аттрибута `android:versionCode` тега `manifest`. И если да, то какое

Comment: Это тип `int` - то есть 32-х разрядное знаковое целое число. То есть максимум: `2 147 483 647`

Comment: хм, откуда уверенность, что имеется в виду int32? В документации этого четко не указано

Answer (score 2):

> android:versionCode — An integer value
> that represents the version of the
> application code, relative to other
> versions. The value is an integer so
> that other applications can
> programmatically evaluate it, for
> example to check an upgrade or
> downgrade relationship. You can set
> the value to any integer you want,
> however you should make sure that each
> successive release of your application
> uses a greater value. The system does
> not enforce this behavior, but
> increasing the value with successive
> releases is normative. Typically, you
> would release the first version of
> your application with versionCode set
> to 1, then monotonically increase the
> value with each release, regardless
> whether the release constitutes a
> major or minor release. This means
> that the android:versionCode value
> does not necessarily have a strong
> resemblance to the application release
> version that is visible to the user
> (see android:versionName, below).
> Applications and publishing services
> should not display this version value
> to users.

Comment: Да, я это видел. Но так и не понял, `integer value` - это int16/int32/int64?

Comment: как минимум 32бита. Все таки android - это java  в основном, а там int уже давно 32битный.

С другой стороны, даже если каждую секунду будете делать сборку, то то хватит на 68 лет. (если считать знаковое) Я думаю, на одно приложение хватит с головой.

Но кто мешает прописать там 11 единичек( что бы было больше 2^32) и посмотреть, что будет. Кто знает, может маркет упадет:)

Comment: хватит на 68 лет, если версию кода увеличивать на 1 при каждой сборке. В последнем релизе случайно версия кода инкрементировалась на много больше. Если int32, то это не строшно. но вот уверенности нет, а проверять на маркете как-то не хочется) К тому же манифест - не джава файл, а Андроид - джава в основном, но не полностью. Вот поэтому и такой вопрос.

Comment: @Ігар Цімошка вот честно я бы сильно удивился если бы оно оказалось int16, ибо смысла в этом ну совсем нет. и никто не мешает проверить практическим путем же. Поставьте versionCode и из приложения попробуйте посмотреть на него

    PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
int versionNumber = pinfo.versionCode;